# Ceil and Floor functions on fractions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is `floor(a/k)=ceil(a/(k+1))` always where `a>=1 and k>=1`? I have tried using the fact that

```
x-1<ceil(a/b)<=x if ceil(a/b)=x  and 
x<=floor(a/b)<x+1 if floor(a/b)=x
```

but unable to reach any conclusion

Comment: No. Consider $a=2$ and $k=1$.

Comment: What if a>1 and k>1

Comment: Still no. Consider $a=6$ and $k=2$.

Comment: Ok I got it, thank you @PeterForeman